# Get LCG from output?

Tags: cryptanalysis, random-number-generator

Given a standard LCG output, let's say 3 consecutive numbers, I'm wondering how I could get $a$ and $c$ if I already know $m$

LCG formula:

*S<sub>n+1</sub> = ( aS<sub>n</sub> + c ) mod m*

I've seen this posted in a lot of places but no one is really giving a math explanation I could understand.

Comment: This is addressed to some degree in this more general [other question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20495/555), and its answers. The present question focuses on case 2, I believe.